# Convert web API 2.0 developed in dotnet 4.5 framework to dotnet Core 2.1.4

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am not much aware about dot net core . I have webapi 2.0 service which I want to convert in dotnet core 2.1.4. Purpose behind this is that I want to host it on Linux rather than windows environment (save cost).I have search over the internet and found a way like project -> properties -> build and change framework to dotnet framework 7.0. I am not sure whether this approach will make it work completely . At the moment I do not have Linux hosting so I can't test whether it will work or not. What is the proper way to convert 4.5 framework web API 2.0 application to dotnet core 2.1.4 ? This application uses EF 6.0 for DB operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any specific code problems that you're having, the best we can do is direct you to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which provides an explanation and examples of how to migrate an ASP.NET Web API project to ASP.NET Core.

**EDIT 1:**

If you don't want to re-write your API you can check out [this blog post](https://koukia.ca/asp-net-web-api-is-dead-long-live-asp-net-core-bd852de1369d) which details how to convert your app to Core with minimal changes. Below is a summarised list of what is required.

- Add the [compatibility shim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/) to your project, via nuget, so that you can keep using ApiController.
- Add a service in Startup.cs to use WebApi conventions such as HttpResponseMessage in action return types.

  ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();
   }
  ```
- Add routing

  ```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
       {
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", api/{controller}/{id?}");
           });
       }
  ```

It is a good idea to convert it with the shims/compatibility libraries in the first instance, to save time and get your app running. But in the longer term I would advise to migrate it properly to use the ASP.NET Core idioms in order to take full advantage of the latest features, bug fixes and perf improvements.

Comment: this is very useful.My code return all response as httpResponseMessage which is a part of "System.Net.Http.Http" namespace. does Dotnet core support this type of message?

Comment: Yes this is supported in .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netcore-3.1